# Colocar Button no final da tela - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Eu tenho uma ExpandableListView e um botão que só deve aparecer quando alguém der o Scroll nela até o final. Eu já tentei colocar como footer mas, se a lista acabar no meio da tela o button fica no meio, eu preciso que ele fique no final e que apenas apareça quando o scroll for dado até o fim.
A imagem abaixo ajuda a explicar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me ajudar? Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fala Tiago,

Você precisará criar uma classe de interface:

```
public interface ScrollViewListener {
    void onScrollChanged(ScrollViewExt scrollView, 
                         int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy);
}
```

Feito isso, você precisará criar uma classe ScrollView:

```
public class ScrollViewExt extends ScrollView {
    private ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener = null;
    public ScrollViewExt(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScrollViewExt(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ScrollViewExt(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setScrollViewListener(ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener) {
        this.scrollViewListener = scrollViewListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (scrollViewListener != null) {
            scrollViewListener.onScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
        }
    }
}
```

Lá no seu layout, você precisará mudar o scrollView:

```
<br.com.seupackage.ScrollViewExt
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</br.com.seupackage.ScrollViewExt>
```

Você declara ele dessa forma no Java, e daclara um listener:

```
ScrollViewExt scroll = (ScrollViewExt) findViewById(R.id.id_scroll);
scroll.setScrollViewListener(this);
```

E por fim, você pode usar o método onScrollChange:

```
@Override
    public void onScrollChanged(ScrollViewExt scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {

        View view = (View) scrollView.getChildAt(scrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
        int diff = (view.getBottom() - (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY()));

        if (diff <= 10) {
            // Se o diff for menor que 10, exibe o botão

        }
    }
```

É um pouco trabalhoso, mas é a solução para usá-lo em um Fragment.

Abraços.

Comment: Eu já faço um extends Fragment, como eu faço para dar outro extend?

Comment: Fala Tiago, esqueci desse detalhe, desculpe, editei minha resposta, da uma olhada como fazer lá.